Sarah and Hagar
The story of Sarah and Hagar is very mysterious to me. I wonder if anyone can open a new angle that I haven't heard about.

I rollbacked to the previous iteration of the question as the newly edited version lacks clarity or focus which is why it was closed.

THis does not show what you have or have not heard


I have heard that Hagar was an Egyptian princess who married Abraham

You are correct. When Avraham and Sara went to Mitzrayim (Egypt), Pharoah famously took Sara hoping to marry her.
The Midrash HaGadol Bereishis 16:1 writes that when he took Sara he wrote into the marriage contract that he was giving his daughter Hagar to her as a maid. The Midrash there relate that this is the meaning behind Hagar's name - i.e. it was a contraction of the words "הא אגרך" - "Here is your (i.e. Sara's) reward.
The Midrash in Bereishis Rabbah 45:1 relates that upon seeing all the nissim (the miracles) that happened to Sara in his palace, he took his daughter and gave her to Avraham, because he reasoned:

מוּטָב שֶׁתְּהֵא בִּתִּי שִׁפְחָה בְּבַיִת זֶה וְלֹא גְבִירָה בְּבַיִת אַחֵר
It is better for my daughter to be a servant in Avraham's house than a mistress in another house


I also wonder why Sara was angry at Abraham that she wasn't getting along with Hagar! Why did she curse Abraham when she was the one who suggested the union in the first place?

Note the Midrash in Bereishis Rabbah 45:4-5

וְהָיוּ מַטְרוֹנִיּוֹת בָּאוֹת לִשְׁאֹל בִּשְׁלוֹמָהּ שֶׁל שָׂרָה וְהָיְתָה שָׂרָה אוֹמֶרֶת לָהֶם צְאוּ וְשַׁאֲלוּ בִּשְׁלוֹמָהּ שֶׁל עֲלוּבָה, וְהָיְתָה הָגָר אוֹמֶרֶת לָהֶם שָׂרַי גְבִרְתִּי אֵין סִתְרָהּ כְּגִלּוּיָהּ, נִרְאֵית צַדֶּקֶת וְאֵינָהּ צַדֶּקֶת, אִלּוּ הָיְתָה צַדֶּקֶת רְאוּ כַּמָּה שָׁנִים שֶׁלֹא נִתְעַבְּרָה וַאֲנִי בְּלַיְלָה אֶחָד נִתְעַבַּרְתִּי, וְהָיְתָה אוֹמֶרֶת עִם דָּא אֲנָא מִסַּב וּמִתַּן, הַלְוַאי מִסַּב וּמִתַּן עִם מָרָהּ. וַתֹּאמֶר שָׂרַי אֶל אַבְרָם חֲמָסִי עָלֶיךָ (בראשית טז, ה), רַבִּי יוּדָן בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בַּר סִימוֹן חוֹמְסֵנִי אַתָּה בִּדְבָרִים, לָמָּה, שֶׁאַתָּה שׁוֹמֵעַ בִּקְלוֹנִי וְשׁוֹתֵק. רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי אַבָּא בַּר כַּהֲנָא אָמַר בָּעֵי דִינִי גַבָּךְ.
Noblewomen would come and inquire after Sarah’s wellbeing, and Sarah would say: ‘Go and inquire after the wellbeing of that meek woman’ [Hagar]. Hagar would say to them: ‘My mistress Sarah, her inner reality is not like her outward impression. She gives the impression of being a righteous woman, but she is not a righteous woman. Were she a righteous woman, look at how many years that she did not conceive, whereas I conceived in one night.’ Sarah would then say: ‘Should I have a discussion with this woman? Better that I should have a discussion with her master.’ “Sarai said to Abram: The injustice done to me is on you. I gave my maidservant into your bosom and she saw that she conceived and I was diminished in her eyes; May the Lord judge between me and you” (Genesis 16:5). “Sarai said to Abram: The injustice done to me [ḥamasi] is on you” – Rabbi Yudan in the name of Rabbi Yehuda bar Simon: You are committing an injustice of words against me, as you hear my humiliation and remain silent. Rabbi Berechya said in the name of Rabbi Abba bar Kahana: [Sarah said:] ‘I have a grievance against you.’


Thank you, a lot is clear now

No problem @Angie - if you feel my response answers you sufficiently, feel free to click the checkmark :-)

Ty 4 pointing it out, I didn't know that feature
